# Can you run pycharm's debugger with an active anaconda environment?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

Is there a way to run pycharm's debugger using an anaconda environment's version of python?

I am able to start an anaconda environment and run scripts from it in the pycharm console. I am not, however, able to run pycharm's debugger properly. When the debugger is run it appears to be using pycharm's default version of python rather than the version that I am using in my anaconda environment.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to run pycharm's debugger using the version of python that is in my active anaconda environment.. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the Project Interpreter in the Settings menu (File->Settings->Project:->Project Interpreter)? I have never had a problem with the debugger using a different environment than the one I set there.

Pycharm's debugger uses the interpreter that the project is configured with. It doesn't appear to be able to use a separate one for debugging purposes.

Comment: I have a separate project interpreter than the one I am using in my anaconda environment- I think this is the problem. Perhaps the debugger exclusively uses the project interpreter and there is not a way to get it to use an active anaconda environment's instead?

Comment: Yeah, I always just set the interpreter as I described to be the anaconda environment that I want to use. Not sure how you would get two separate ones to cooperate.

Comment: Looks like that's the answer then- thanks for the clarification